# Setting MKMapKit region fails in test

Tags: swift, mapkit, xctest

Building a layout in code, things are fine until I need to set the region of the map:

```
    if let coordinate = item.location?.coordinate {

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 100, 100)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
        let regionM = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
        print(mapView.centerCoordinate)
        print(coordinate)
        print(region)

        mapView.region = region
        mapView.region.center = coordinate
        mapView.regionThatFits(region)
        mapView.setCenter(coordinate, animated: false)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        mapView.setRegion(regionM, animated: false)
        print(mapView.region)
        print(region)

    }
```

This is the test which fails:

```
func test_SettingItemInfo_SetsMapLocation() {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.2277, 6.7735)
    let location = Location(name: "Cool", coordinate: coordinate)

    let item = Item(title: "Here", location: location)
    manager.add(item)
    sut.info = (manager, 0)

    sut.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
    sut.endAppearanceTransition()

    // possibly asynchronous
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, coordinate.latitude, accuracy: 0.001)
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude, coordinate.longitude, accuracy: 0.001)
}
```

This is the result from print logs:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.787685747888986, longitude: -122.40971999999998)
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.227699999999999, longitude: 6.7735000000000003)
MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.227699999999999, longitude: 6.7735000000000003), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.00089885544064104096, longitudeDelta: 0.0014315673851581932))
MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.787685747888986, longitude: -122.40971999999998), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 90.0, longitudeDelta: 180.0))
MKCoordinateRegion(center: __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.227699999999999, longitude: 6.7735000000000003), span: __C.MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.00089885544064104096, longitudeDelta: 0.0014315673851581932))
```

and this is the failing test log:

```
error: -[TDDS4ToDoTests.DetailViewControllerTests test_SettingItemInfo_SetsMapLocation] : XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy failed: ("37.787685747889") is not equal to ("51.2277") +/- ("0.001") - 
error: -[TDDS4ToDoTests.DetailViewControllerTests test_SettingItemInfo_SetsMapLocation] : XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy failed: ("-122.40972") is not equal to ("6.7735") +/- ("0.001") - 
Test Case '-[TDDS4ToDoTests.DetailViewControllerTests test_SettingItemInfo_SetsMapLocation]' failed (213.944 seconds).
```

Ideally, the first line should have fixed the region, yet I experimented with a few different ways (as shown above).
Is the call to `mapview.region` not set immediately because it is asynchronous?

Comment: Looks like you are running on iPhone simulator and the location is set to Apple and not your custom location.

Comment: thank you, @MwcsMac. I didn't have the location set before- yet even if it were, shouldn't I still be able to update the region to pass the test?

Comment: update: set the custom location to the exact coordinates in my test and it still sets to the incorrect ones (shown above). Could there be any other possibilities for why this behaves in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything inside MKMapView is updated asynchronously. You need to use an XCTestExpectation (or similar) to listen for MKMapViewDelegate callbacks.

This is an unbelievably tedious and difficult thing to test - full of subtle pitfalls. Putting this self-contained test here for posterity:

```swift
import MapKit
import XCTest

/// a callback to pipe region changes into our test
protocol MapViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func regionChanged(to mapRect: MKMapRect)
}

/// the view controller we want to test
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    weak var delegate: MapViewControllerDelegate?

    var mapView: MKMapView {
        return view as! MKMapView
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = self
        view = mapView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.regionChanged(to: mapView.visibleMapRect)
    }

}

/// a "Spy pattern"-like object for capturing the inputs we want to validate with our test
class Delegate: MapViewControllerDelegate {

    var mapRect: MKMapRect?
    var regionChangedExpectation: XCTestExpectation?

    func regionChanged(to mapRect: MKMapRect) {
        guard let regionChangedExpectation = regionChangedExpectation else {
            XCTFail("Delegate was not setup correctly. Missing expectation reference")
            return
        }

        self.mapRect = mapRect
        regionChangedExpectation.fulfill()
    }
}

/// our tests
class TestCase: XCTestCase {

    var viewController: MapViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        viewController = MapViewController()

        // force the view to load
        _ = viewController.view

        // VERY IMPORTANT: If you don't put the map view in a window none of the delegate callbacks get fired.
        // I assume this is some kind of MapKit optimization.
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
    }

    func testExample() {
        // set up an expectation to test the async call
        let regionChangedExpectation = expectation(description: "Should update region")
        regionChangedExpectation.expectedFulfillmentCount = 1

        // create our Spy object to stand in for our usual delegate
        let delegate = Delegate()
        delegate.regionChangedExpectation = regionChangedExpectation
        viewController.delegate = delegate

        // the test region
        var firstRect = MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(x: 61089821.0, y: 110138019.04306149),
                                              size: MKMapSize(width: 361250.00249999744, height: 691590.91387700045))

        // adjust the mapRect so it fits the mapView
        firstRect = viewController.mapView.mapRectThatFits(firstRect, edgePadding: .zero)

        // trigger a map viewport change
        viewController.mapView.visibleMapRect = firstRect

        // block and wait for the async call to finish
        wait(for: [regionChangedExpectation], timeout: 10)

        // make sure we received the region change
        guard let mapRect = delegate.mapRect else {
            XCTFail("no visible map rect set")
            return
        }

        // make sure we received the RIGHT region change
        XCTAssertEqual(firstRect.origin.y, mapRect.origin.y, accuracy: 0.002)
        XCTAssertEqual(firstRect.origin.x, mapRect.origin.x, accuracy: 0.002)
        XCTAssertEqual(firstRect.size.width, mapRect.size.width, accuracy: 0.002)
        XCTAssertEqual(firstRect.size.height, mapRect.size.height, accuracy: 0.002)
    }

}
```